# Can a DBF file contains more than one table?

Tags: dbf

I want to export my tables into DBF format so I was wondering if I can export multiple table into a single DBF file. As far as I know one DBF file can contain on table.

Comment: A DBF is a table. It can't contain more than one, because it is one.

Comment: @KenWhite I agree that's what I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 4):

One `dbf` file contains one table.  Likewise, one memo file contains the memos for one table.